# MS Access checkbox triple state property

Tags: ms-access

I know that I can disable the MS Access Checkbox's triple state property from the checkbox's property sheet.

[image]

By setting it to false a user can only select either true or false as the value for the checkbox.

However, everytime the form opens it looks like the default state is selected which looks something like this:

[image]

I think this is rather confusing for a user as this default state looks like the check box is already selected. Is there a way to make the checkbox start as blank or false?

Comment: Is this a bound checkbox? If it is and the Boolean column in the table or query has a default value, it will remove the triple state.

Comment: Set DefaultValue property to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DefaultValue in the underlying table that the checkbox or option button is 'bound' to should be set to 0. At creation of a new record, the value displayed by the control will be a blank box / option.